# Facebook preview image doesn't match scraper information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I just recently launched a game on steam, and when I share a link in facebook the preview image doesn't appear.

I ran the [object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstore.steampowered.com%2Fapp%2F455980%2F).

From the results, in the og:image field, I can see the image correctly, however in the preview itself the image is broken.

Any ideas?

Edit: Since this is a steam page, my ability to influence it is limited. I can only change some images, but I cannot add meta tags.
I did find, however, in this post, that a `<link rel="image_src" href="/myimage.jpg"/>` tag should also be identifiable by facebook as a preview image. For some reason in my page facebook either ignores this or treats the image as invalid (although it is larger than 200x200)

Comment: That page has no Open Graph meta information at all – so what will be displayed depends on luck.

Comment: Yeah I know, but all steam pages are the same and they all work fine. Moreover, I can see what "luck" (not really luck, heuristic algorithm) chose - in the og:image field - and it's what I want shown, but for some reason it's not displayed.

Comment: Debug tool clearly says that it chose http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/game/game_highlight_image_spacer.gif as the image to display. Again, the only way to be certain what will be displayed, is to implement OG meta tags. If the Steam guys are not willing to do that, than they/you will have to live with results such as this.

Comment: I've asked them but I do not expect anything, so I'm going to have to deal with this myself. I am able to upload the images displayed on the page, and since 90% of the other steam pages work fine, I expect I should be able to find a way within these limitations, if I only understood why the crawler works differently in my page than other steam pages.

Comment: The error in the debug tool states that http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/game/game_highlight_image_spacer.gif will be displayed *instead* of the image it found (the one in link rel I guess) because of size/download issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
og:image could not be downloaded or is too small
og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough.
Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image 
that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook.
'http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/game/game_highlight_image_spacer.gif' will be used instead.
Consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for more troubleshooting tips.
```

So we do have the reason why it is blank (spacer.gif is blank)

[image: Screenshot dev tools chrome]
This is the same for other pages as well...

http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/455980/header.jpg?t=1459222551 <-- Can be found in the header...

So lets have a closer look at the image itself...

The images are creatd ondemand (so it seems) and you (a.jpg) is the same as Cities Skylines (b.jpg)

[image: IrfanView Image information]

So no idea at all... Maybe a problem with Steam's CDN (FB is unable to find the image. Did you update the image recently?)

Sorry not to be able to help. The image itself cannot be faulty IMHO as stream is processing the image every time...

Cannot say more :/

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth analysis. Too bad it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Well, I said "nothing to do with your picture". You might need to do something on the "admin page" of the game... Or let FB some time to update it...

Answer (score 0):

When content is shared for the first time, the Facebook crawler will scrape and cache the metadata from the URL shared. The crawler has to see an image at least once before it can be rendered. This means that the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered image:

1. Pre-cache the image with the URL Debugger
   Run the URL through the URL debugger to pre-fetch metadata for the page. You should also do this if you update the image for a piece of content.
2. Use og:image:width and og:image:height Open Graph tags
   Using these tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can render it immediately without having to asynchronously.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Hi, Thank you but as I stated in my question - the URL debugger returns weird answers, which is what I am trying to figure out. I can't add any headers such as og:image, since this is a store page in a portal, and I don't have direct access to the html. Still, many other pages in that same portal work fine without these tags.